# Ajax calls in windows phone

Tags: ajax, cordova, windows-phone-8

When I'm deploying on registered windows 8 phone using xap deployment tool, Ajax request work fine. But when I put on the windows phone market for beta the request doesn't work.
I am working with phonegap build 3.5.0. so I can't see the project.

Comment: why don't you put alerts at function calls. This will help you to debug, even though it may not be the smartest way to find an error.

Comment: Yes I did it, and I Know that entry in succes function with an empty string as parameter data, I know that the call don't arrive to the server too.